# improve performance of octave plot with many lines

Tags: performance, optimization, graph, plot, octave

I wonder if there is a faster approach to create a 3D plot of multiple lines. See below for a function that simulates my current approach with some dummy data. Essentially, what I'm doing, is plotting multiple 2D lines next to each other in a 3D space to quickly compare them. Each individual line is colored by its final y value.

```
function test_plotmany(lines = 1000, points = 100)
    # this data comes from a numeric simulation, here I just fill
    # it with some dummy values - ignore this
    t = [1:points];
    data = [];
    for i = t;
        data(end + 1, :) = [1:lines] .* i;
    endfor

    # now the actually interesting part that I want to speed up, if possible
    tic;
    tsize = size(t, 2);
    const = ones(tsize, 1);

    lines = [1:size(data, 2)];
    colors = jet(size(lines, 2));
    colormap(colors);
    cIdx = 1;

    figure
    hold on;
    for i = lines;
        plot3(t, data(1, i) .* const, data(:, i), 'Color', colors(cIdx, :));
        cIdx = cIdx + 1;
    endfor
    xlabel("Foo");
    ylabel("Bar");
    zlabel("Baz");
    grid("on");
    view(45, 45);
    set(gca, 'XScale', 'linear', 'YScale', 'log', 'ZScale', 'log');
    cb = colorbar;
    caxis([min(data(tsize, :)), max(data(tsize, :))]);
    set(get(cb, 'ylabel'), 'string', 'Something');
    hold off;
    toc;
endfunction
```

The outcome for `test_plotmany(100, 100)` is shown below, and took already 2s. The size of a real data set I have to deal with can be simulated with `test_plotmany(10000, 100)`, which takes minutes on my machine to create.

[image]

Is there anything I can do differently to speed this up? Is there maybe a way to create a 3D matrix or such and hand that over to a 3D plot function to recreate my graph? Or could I use multiple threads to render the graph?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Note: I'm using GNU Octave, version 3.8.1 on Linux 3.16.1-1-ARCH with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz. In Octave, I use the fltk graphics_toolkit - gnuplot does not work for the above at all for me (colors are wrong, cannot interact with the graph to rotate, zoom or pan it).

Comment: Are you sure you need to compare these 2D lines in 3D space? Most of the times this is not a good idea. The interpretation can be enourmously affected by the view angle.

Comment: If you have another suggestion on how to tackle this, then by all means tell me. I previously used a pure 2D view and that did not help me at all. With the 3D view I can rotate and inspect the view at will and I find this very intuitive.

Comment: I would go with 2D: simpler/faster code plus easier interpretation. If you are only comparing curves, 3D is unnecessary complexity.

Comment: stacking them all on top of each other doesn't make it simpler, quite the contrary... then I'll just see gibberish lines of random colors without the ability to differentiate them based on e.g. the "Bar" value.

also while I agree that 2D is simpler and faster, I do wonder whether there is any technique which would speed up the above.